# Xdebug doesn't stop at breakline

Tags: php, zend-framework, netbeans, xdebug

Alright so my xdebug doesn't work properly. I had it to stop at a breakpoint before, but then it wouldn't so I tried to modify some stuff and now it isn't even working in the previous condition.

But i does however stop at the first block code level. like this:

[image]

But then again I changed some stuff so now it isn't working anymore. And my  debugger console is empty too. (has always been? :/)

[image]

Now it only stops where the breakpoint is, but if I remove it or change it to another place. It'll not stop anywhere.

I'll provide you with as much information as you need.

Netbeans information:

```
Product Version: NetBeans IDE 7.2.1 (Build 201210100934)
Java: 1.7.0_10; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 23.6-b04
System: Windows 7 version 6.1 running on amd64; Cp1252; en_US (nb)
```

xdebug

```
xdebug support  enabled
Version 2.2.2
IDE Key netbeans-xdebug

Supported protocols Revision
DBGp - Common DeBuGger Protocol $Revision: 1.145 $

Directive   Local Value Master Value
xdebug.auto_trace   Off Off
xdebug.cli_color    0   0
xdebug.collect_assignments  Off Off
xdebug.collect_includes On  On
xdebug.collect_params   0   0
xdebug.collect_return   Off Off
xdebug.collect_vars Off Off
xdebug.coverage_enable  On  On
xdebug.default_enable   On  On
xdebug.dump.COOKIE  no value    no value
xdebug.dump.ENV no value    no value
xdebug.dump.FILES   no value    no value
xdebug.dump.GET no value    no value
xdebug.dump.POST    no value    no value
xdebug.dump.REQUEST no value    no value
xdebug.dump.SERVER  no value    no value
xdebug.dump.SESSION no value    no value
xdebug.dump_globals On  On
xdebug.dump_once    On  On
xdebug.dump_undefined   Off Off
xdebug.extended_info    On  On
xdebug.file_link_format no value    no value
xdebug.idekey   netbeans-xdebug netbeans-xdebug
xdebug.max_nesting_level    100 100
xdebug.overload_var_dump    On  On
xdebug.profiler_aggregate   Off Off
xdebug.profiler_append  Off Off
xdebug.profiler_enable  Off Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger  Off Off
xdebug.profiler_output_dir  C:\xampp\tmp    C:\xampp\tmp
xdebug.profiler_output_name xdebug_profile.%R::%u   xdebug_profile.%R::%u
xdebug.remote_autostart Off Off
xdebug.remote_connect_back  Off Off
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time    3600    3600
xdebug.remote_enable    On  On
xdebug.remote_handler   dbgp    dbgp
xdebug.remote_host  127.0.0.1   127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_log   no value    no value
xdebug.remote_mode  req req
xdebug.remote_port  9000    9000
xdebug.scream   Off Off
xdebug.show_exception_trace Off Off
xdebug.show_local_vars  Off Off
xdebug.show_mem_delta   Off Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger Off Off
xdebug.trace_format 0   0
xdebug.trace_options    0   0
xdebug.trace_output_dir C:\xampp\tmp    C:\xampp\tmp
xdebug.trace_output_name    trace.%c    trace.%c
xdebug.var_display_max_children 128 128
xdebug.var_display_max_data 512 512
xdebug.var_display_max_depth    3   3
```

I'm running **PHP version 5.4.4** and

**Apache Version    Apache/2.4.2 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.4
Apache API Version.**

[image]

[image]

[image]

I also tried the ZendDebugger, but that gave me a php5.dll file is missing error.

Comment: I've been trying to solve this for hours. So now I need someone who actually has an explanation why I'm getting the error. Or at least how I can fix it.

Comment: Oh, btw this seems to be explicit for Zend.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the problem is your code isn't synchronized between your IDE and your webserver. I see you're running on localhost, so, you need to make sure the files are getting saved in the right directory for your web server to pick it up. You're probably debugging an older version of your code. It happened to me several times running code on a VM.